# Lua sethook with 'r' will not trigger when lua function go out by exception

Tags: lua, hook

I use lua `sethook` to check every function return time, and then I find a problem: those lua functions go out by exception will not trigger the hook, and then the count will not be critical. can anyone solve this problem?

Comment: `debug.sethook` seems to work for me. Please give us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Even functions without `return` statement have `return` instruction inside its bytecode.  But you can leave the function by generating an exception...

Comment: @ Egor Skriptunoff Thanks for your reply, It's true that this doesn't cause by return. I edit my question now.